# Unix Script for Visiting Website

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cron

I would like to create a unix script that will automatically visit a certain link on my linux system (at port 22).

I want it to visit the link twice per day.

I have `gedit` and `-bash-4.1$.`

What code should I use to do this?

How do I execute/run the program?

Comment: Do you need to do anything with the result of the curl command, or is it sufficient to just hit the web site without worrying about what response you get ?

Comment: It is sufficient just to hit the website.

Answer (score 0):

- You said "port 22", you may need to use the curl parameter for it (through a website shall usually not be at port 22 but at port 80).
- Why would you use gedit ?
- As far as I know, Linux doesn't really care what extension you use. Anyway, the best is **.sh**.
- If you use a GUI Linux, you should open it like any other file. If you prefer the terminal, use **bash path/to/file.sh**

Comment: How do I get the program to run on its own?

Comment: On a server (like VPSs), you would use a tool like **tmux**. Also, you have to make your script to be a loop with a long wait (12h for twice a day).